# Kindle Web Reader (amazon ebooks) Dark Mode

Tags: amazon, website, kindle, dark-mode

Right know, even with Dark Reader (chrome extension), there's no good dark mode for Kindle Web Reader, is there any way to customize this web UI?

Answer (score 1):

yep.

1. using a css customizer like:

   - https://stylebot.dev/ (recommended)
   - https://userstyles.org/
2. copy the CSS style code.

   - source (theme): [kindle-web-reader.dark.css](https://gist.github.com/rbatty19/dda750e0507644f1a0d6b030a75d92d7)
3. Use the CSS Customizer to overwrite with the new style:

#### Tutorial (stylebot):

- Locate and click the CSS customizer.
  [image]
- Open the config (i.e: Open Stylebot)

[image]

- Paste the css you copied before.

[image]

#### Result (screenshots):

[image]

> theme

[image]

> search (with mouse hover)

[image]

> notebook (with mouse hover)